# What is the freezing point of 100LL Avgas?

Tags: fuel, fuel-systems, avgas

Does anyone knows the exact freezing point of Avgas (100LL) ?

I found that Jet A-1 freezes at ***−47 °C*** / ***−53 °F*** ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_fuel#Jet_A)), but didn't manage to find any info on Avgas.

Comment: Are you asking for some particular purpose (like you're designing a system where you need to keep avgas from freezing), or out of curiosity?

Comment: @TannerSwett Just out of curiosity ^^

Comment: Avgas, which is gasoline, must sustain -58°C, this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpGrH.png) from [ACRP Overview of Airport Fueling Operations](https://www.nap.edu/catalog/22141/overview-of-airport-fueling-operations)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ExxonMobil China says](https://www.exxonmobil.com/english-CN/Commercial-Fuel/pds/GLXXAvgas-Series) their Avgas 100LL will not freeze above -58°C.

[image]

The 'typical' freezing temperature is not given, but I would expect we'd be more interested in the maximum freezing temperature.

Comment: @ymb1 Nice edit. How did you do that?!

Comment: :D - software called snagit.